# Returning string from Android Activity started with `startActivityForResult` inside `onClickListener` returns null

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

I use an `Intent` in `MainActivity` to start another `Activity` called `MatchesActivity` using `startActivityForResult`. I put breakpoints at `finish()` inside the started activity (`MatchesActivity`) and on the `Log` statement inside `onActivityResult` because I got NPE inside `onActivityResult`.

`intent.getStringExtra("TXAMATCHES")` contains what it should.

But `Intent data` comes back `null`.

Is this likely/possibly because I start the `Intent` inside an `onClick` listener?

Or because `MatchesActivity` calls a method in another class that extends `AsyncTask` and the data is what that task produces? (But the correct data is found in `txaMatches` just before it is returned to `MainActivity`...)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    ...
  btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override public void onClick(View v) 
  {
    ...
    Intent matchesIntent;
    matchesIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MatchesActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(matchesIntent, 0);
    ...
  }
  ...
  @Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
  {
    Log.w("MainActivity","" + onActivityResult " + data.getStringExtra("TXAMATCHES"));
  }
}
```

...

```
public class MatchesActivity extends Activity implements DatabaseConnector.DatabaseProcessListener
{
  ...
  @Override protected void onDestroy()
  {
    super.onDestroy();
    finishThisAndReturnString();

  }
  public void finishThisAndReturnString()
  {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("TXAMATCHES",txaMatches.getText().toString());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
  }
```

(The started `Activity` is terminated by user pressing `back` icon.)

Comment: do you load the `String` from somewhere in the `onClickListener()`?

Comment: "But Intent data comes back null." -- um, well, you're not supplying a `Uri` to the `Intent`. Hence, `getData()` will return `null`. I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: @CommonsWare--Well, I definitely am missing something. Uncharted waters. I'll review the parameters. Hope it's that easy.

Comment: @helldawg13--The String is loaded in a class twice removed from where the `onClickListener` is found, which is `MainActivity`, which starts `MatchesActivity` as an `ActivityForResult', which calls a method in  `DatabaseConnector` that is an `AsyncTask`, which is where the String is created.

Comment: @CommonsWare--Examples I've seen have had the Intent (that was started for result) return the value via `Intent intent = new Intent(   )` with no parameters. So I'm not sure where I need to specify the `Uri` or what it should be...

Comment: @CommonsWare--Although I always value your comments and Answers and would have liked a reply to my previous comment, never mind. Only problem was apparently having `onDestroy` call method that invokes `finish`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not correct. You're trying to call `finish()` on the `onDestroy()` method. `onDestroy()` gets called when the Activity is about to be killed. So basically calling `finish()` at that point is wrong.

I assume that you are trying to do some processing in the `AsyncTask`. I suggest that you call the `finish()` method on the `onPostExecute`() method of the AsyncTask.

Comment: @Ruchira--I essentially had already done what your second paragraph suggests. My `onPostExecute` method invokes `interface` `ProcessingIsDone` with parameter `true`, which immediately directs control to `finishThisAndReturnString`. And your first paragraph fixed my problem as did the previous Answer of @Cl

Answer (score 2):

You can't finish a activity in the onDestroy method. In this lifecycle phase the activity is already dying.

The call of the finish() method will call the onDestroy, not the other.

Call the finish method when you want to to finish the MatchesActivity.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the data in the Intent object in `onDestroy()` method . So in this case, whenever you call `setResult()`  in `onDestroy()` method, you will always get resultCode in `onActivityResult()` as '0' which is the value for `RESULT_CANCELED` and whenever you get `RESULT_CANCELED` in  `onActivityResult()` you get `data` object null. That's why you don't get the values you set in Intent .

Answer (score 0):

First try to get the value of

> txaMatches.getText().toString()

Check this value in the MatchesActivity Class.

It is possible that it is returning null value due to which u are getting the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed by removing `finishThisAndReturnString()` from `onDestroy`, as stated in the first two Answers.